# Imbalanced speakers, static from one, sound from other, while on UPS

Tags: audio, speakers

I have a pair of creative 2.1 speakers, which developed some problem with the 3.5 mm pin. So I chopped it off, and soldered my own. Now, whenever there is a power loss, and the UPS picks up the slack, I hear static from the left speaker, and good audio, w/o static from the right. Decreasing the volume from the remote, decreases the volume, so the static can be clearly heard.

But, exchanging the Left/Right channel pins at the back of the sub-woofer, doesn't do the exact opposite. I mean, the sound and static does get exchanged between channels, but decreasing the volume on the remote down to zero, and you can hear some leakage audio from the right channel, which was'nt coming in thhe prev test config. Weird?

Have I improperly soldered the 3.5 mm jack? Are there different qualities/ratings for the same dimension audio jacks? I live in a semi-rural place, So, giving exact specifications wont help, because I wont be able to procure it, but worth a shot.

Thanks

Comment: So, *only* when using the UPS, right? I guess that should go into the title then?

Comment: Or is the UPS not powering the speakers?

Comment: the UPS powers the speakers, but actually the UPS powers the entire house, not just the PC. I am guessing some voltage dip?

Comment: Any idea if the UPS somehow fully disconnects your connection with the main power lines? If so: then maybe you no longer have a proper [ground/earth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_%40electricity%41) anymore. (Do you indeed use a power plug that has 2 pins for the mains power, and some additional pin for the ground? Still then, if the UPS powers the whole house, then I guess things are grounded somehow.)

Comment: well, i do use a 2 pin plug for the speakers, the one that it came with. And the electrical wiring is properly grounded, because I dont feel any shocks, using the computer, or any other appliance. I guess the UPS gives a dirty voltage, because the TV makes a weird noise when turned on.

Comment: I don't know how the following new questions can help you, but maybe someone else gets the Eureka... The 3.5 mm jack you replaced, was that the stereo jack that goes into the computer, or was it a mono plug from a specific speaker? What do you hear if you unplug the speakers from the computer altogether (but leave the sub-woofer powered on)? Or any chance to hook it up to some other audio device? What if you reverse the mains power plug while running on the UPS? And just to be sure: you've also used the UPS before you soldered your own plug, without these issues, right? Interesting!

Comment: the jack i replaced was the one that goes on the mobo. i hear static when I remove the speakers from the mobo. yeah, i have used the speakers prev to this prob, but they were OEM plugs, so that contibutes to something too. Ill try and do a better soldering, and see how it goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common fault when soldering audio jacks is to apply too much heat to the screen, causing it to melt the insulation on the signal wires and partly or completely short one of the channels to earth. Recheck your soldering.

Comment: ok, ill check the soldering.